# How can I indicate to screen readers which of a series of words is the active/selected one?

Tags: html, css, accessibility, screen-readers

On a web page, I have a bit of text indicating the level of difficulty of something. Among the choices are easy, moderate, and difficult.

It is displayed like so:

[image: Example of difficulty indicator: "Level of Effort: Easy Moderate Difficult"]

The indicated difficulty level is "Difficult" among the three. This would be styled visually, but I worry that screen readers would just read "Level of Difficulty: Easy, Moderate, Difficult," which wouldn't make sense to anybody.

Right now the HTML is something simple like:

```html
<div ...>
    <div class="some-field its-inline-too">
        <div class="field-label">Level of Difficulty</div>
        <div class="field-value">
            <span class="difficulty">Easy</span>
            <span class="difficulty">Moderate</span>
            <span class="difficulty active">Difficult</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What kind of HTML tags and/or styling can I utilize, that would *keep* the current visual styling, but also add something that would indicate to screen readers that only one of the selections is the *actual* one, of the three?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use the `aria-current="true"` attribute on the element.

> The aria-current attribute is used when an element within a set of related elements is visually styled to indicate it is the current item in the set.

```
<div ...>
    <div class="some-field its-inline-too">
        <div class="field-label">Level of Difficulty</div>
        <div class="field-value">
            <span class="difficulty">Easy</span>
            <span class="difficulty">Moderate</span>
            <span class="difficulty" aria-current="true">Difficult</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[See screenreader support](http://design-patterns.tink.uk/aria-current/)

It should not be confused with `aria-selected` which should be used for interactive (activable) elements.

Comment: Would this be preferable over using `aria-hidden="true"` on the other two options instead?

Comment: Of course. `aria-hidden` should never be used for visible elements as it will hide their transcription for screen readers and cause major accessibility problems for partially blind users.

Answer (score 1):

If it isn't interactive, I would go for making inactive/irrelevant elements `aria-hidden`.

Using `aria-current=true`, `aria-selected`, or making a word like "selected" be said by the screen reader by whatever mean can give the impression that the element is interactive.
The screen reader user will think that he can change the selection in some way, notice after a while that in fact he can't, won't understand, and finally will maybe think that the site doesn't work or is unaccessible.

Having all the words showing all possible levels in order probably doesn't give much information, so it doesn't harm if only the current active one is shown.
In case the different words indicating the different levels aren't clear enough, you'd better choose other words or explain in another page what are the levels and what they correspond to, or replace by numbers, e.g. 1/3=easy, 2/3=medium and 3/3=difficult.

Of course if the elements are interactive, it goes the other way round: **don't ever ever use `aria-hidden`**.
Use `aria-current`, `aria-selected`, etc. according to the type of interactive element, or one million times better, use real form elements, buttons, links, etc. instead of div/span+ARIA emulated ones.

Answer (score 0):

Use [visually hidden text](https://a11yproject.com/posts/how-to-hide-content/)

**HTML**

```
<div ...>
    <div class="some-field its-inline-too">
        <div class="field-label">Level of Difficulty</div>
        <div class="field-value">
            <span class="difficulty">Easy</span>
            <span class="difficulty">Moderate</span>
            <span class="difficulty active">Difficult<span class="visually-hidden"> selected</span></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.visually-hidden {
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px; width: 1px; 
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
}
```

This would let the screen reader interpret the content as:

```
level of difficulty
easy moderate difficult selected
```

I would also recommend using a heading tag or some other type of label for your label and a list where you have the list of difficulties, for example:

```
<div ...>
    <div class="some-field its-inline-too">
        <h3 class="field-label">Level of Difficulty</h3>
        <ul class="field-value">
            <li class="difficulty">Easy</li>
            <li class="difficulty">Moderate</li>
            <li class="difficulty active">Difficult<span class="visually-hidden"> selected</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using semantic HTML will help screen reader users to better understand the context.

Comment: Oh no, this is not interactive. Purely indicative of a difficulty level set for a particular article (in Drupal).

Comment: Don't you think it might be confusing for a blind user, for example, hearing "easy moderate difficult selected"? Isn't there something...more that I can do?

Comment: It could potentially be confusing but you can use visually hidden and `aria-hidden` to achieve any experience that you think is best. You could add `aria-hidden` to unselected options and add text to indicate that there are more options available. For example you could make the text read `Level of difficulty difficult easy and moderate also available` by adding visually hidden text after the list.

Comment: I have also just discovered `aria-hidden`, which I can use to hide the inactive field values.